# Pass object fields and one2many fields on same method - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have this method:

```
@api.multi
def create_print(self,vals):
    rec_production_order = self.env['bsi.production.order'].search([], order='id desc', limit=1)
    self.env['bsi.print.order'].create({
        'origin': rec_production_order.name,
        'state': 'draft',
    })
    if order_lines in rec_production_order:
        vals.update({'order_lines':[(0,0,
            {
            'isbn':'isbn',
            'qty':'consumed_qty',
            })]})
        return super(bsi_print_order,self).create(vals)
```

This method is on `'bsi.production.order'` object, these are the objects I'm using:

```
class bsi_production_order(models.Model):
_name = 'bsi.production.order'
_inherit = ['product.product']

@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if vals.get('name', 'New') == 'New':
        if vals.get('production_type') == 'budgeted':
            vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.production.budgeted') or '/'
        elif vals.get('production_type') == 'nonbudgeted':
            vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.production.non_budgeted') or '/'
        elif vals.get('production_type') == 'direct':
            vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.production.direct') or '/'
    return super(bsi_production_order, self).create(vals)

name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')
date = fields.Date(string="Production Date")
notes = fields.Text(string="Notes")
order_lines = fields.One2many('bsi.production.order.lines', 'production_order', states={'finished': [('readonly', True)], 'cancel': [('readonly', True)]}, string="Order lines", copy=True)
print_orders = fields.One2many('bsi.print.order', 'production_orders', string="Print Orders")

class bsi_print_order(models.Model):
_name = 'bsi.print.order'
_inherit = ['mail.thread','mrp.worksheet.contract'] 

name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')
date = fields.Date(string="Print Date")
production_orders = fields.Many2one('bsi.production.order', ondelete='cascade', string="Production Order")
origin = fields.Char(string="Origin")
due_date = fields.Date(string="Due Date")
state = fields.Selection([
    ('draft','Draft'),
    ('awaitingraw','Awaiting raw materials'),
    ('wip','Work in Progress'),
    ('delivered','Delivered'),
    ('cancel','Cancel'),
], string="State")
notes = fields.Text(string="Notes")

class bsi_print_order_lines(models.Model):
_name = 'bsi.print.order.lines'

print_order = fields.Many2one('bsi.print.order', string="Print Order")
production_orders = fields.Many2one('bsi.production.order', ondelete='cascade', string="Production Order")
isbn = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="ISBN", domain="[('is_isbn', '=', True)]")
qty = fields.Integer(string="Quantity")
consumed_qty = fields.Integer(string="Quantity consumed")
remaining_qty = fields.Float(string="Remaining quantity", compute="_remaining_func")
state = fields.Selection([
        ('draft','Draft'),
        ('inprogress','In progress'),
        ('readytomove','Ready to move'),
        ('intransit','In transitt'),
        ('done','Done'),
    ], string="State")
is_book_block = fields.Boolean(string="Is Book Block Done")
is_binding = fields.Boolean(string="Is Binding Done")
is_edging = fields.Boolean(string="Is Edging Done")

@api.onchange('qty', 'consumed_qty')
def _remaining_func(self):
    if self.consumed_qty or self.qty:
        self.remaining_qty = self.consumed_qty - self.qty
```

I want to pass records from current form in `bsi.production.order`, to `bsi.print.order` and `bsi.print.order.lines`, every time I click on the aforementioned method it throws me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 583, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 319, in _call_function
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 812, in __call__
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 948, in call_button
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 399, in old_api
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\bsi\models\models.py", line 381, in create_print
NameError: global name 'order_lines' is not defined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if you call this method from the button no need to fetch any record
because self (RecordSet) will contain only that record but it's better
to loop any way if you want to call this method in using odoo-API.

```py
def @api.multi
def create_print(self,vals):
    # first define the empty model to call create from
    copy_record = self.env['other.model'] # now you call the method directly
    for record in self:
        # like this is safer
        # here create a list of cammands for you new o2m_field

        o2m_field = []
        for rec in record.o2m_field:
            # here loop through all o2m record to create the list of commands
            o2m_field.append(
             (0,0,
             {
                'some_field': rec.some_field,
                'some_field2': rec.some_field2,
                'some_m2o_field': rec.some_m2o_field.id,# m2o pass interger value
                # hope you don't have o2m_field here too. or you need to use imagination to create
                # a good method that creates this list of commands.
                }
            )


        # now create the record
        copy_record.create(
        {
          'simple_field' : record.simple_field, # for simple field type char,date,...
          'm2o_field': record.m2o_field.id, # pass the id always
          'o2m_field': o2m_field, # here we pass the list of commands that we created earlier
        })
```

I think you got the idea copy a record is a very complicated operation specially when there is m2m and o2m field in the copy too.

Comment: I need to save the one2many 'order_lines' field, but I need to specify what fields should be saved, I guess I cannot just save by self.order_lines, I need to specify them, I've changed 'order_lines' to 'self.order_lines' and it says 'mixing apples with oranges'

Comment: Obviously this would be saved on another model 'bsi.print.order'

Comment: Is it possible to pass order_lines without any conditional?

Comment: edit your question and explain the scenario a little bit more and about the new error generally it shows when you mix types

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I need to pass these into the other model, the create_print is okay as it is, what I don't know or understand is how to pass those on the very same method, I guess values.update isn't the way to go.

Comment: My whole point is to pass the one2many, but it should be inside create_print method, that is what I still don't get, because, there are fields on the one2many, but there are some fields outside of it too. What I don't understand is how to do this inside the method which is there already (create_print) I did the (if order_lines in rec_production_order: vals.update ...) because I really don't know how to do both things on the same method.

Comment: Think about purchase.order and sale.order, both of them have lines (one2many), I need to create a bsi.print.order, which has bsi.print.order.lines, from bsi.production.order and bsi.production.order.lines, every object goes to it's counterpart. I don't know if I'm explaining well... The problem with purchase and sale, is that these are old api methods, so that's why I'm confused in how to achieve this in the new api.

Comment: So `bsi.print.order`  have a one2many field that need to have same records that are in a one2many field of `bsi.production.order`  It's like you are duplicating the record in the other model and you want to pass the same values from `bsi.production.order` to `bsi.print.order` sorry if i don't understand my english is not that good

Comment: Yes, that's totally right, no problem, You understood perfectly, Thanks

Comment: i don't know if my answer will help you this time but what you want is very complicated and need to much test to write an elegant code

Comment: Thank You very much, gonna test it :), lol, there's no other one2many field, thankfully hehe